# Variable is iterable in local but not in live server

Tags: javascript, node.js, unzip, ovh

when I try this function in local to dezip files that we download, it work well

```
const unzipFiles = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const dirname = process.cwd() + '/data_files/csv/Rakuten/';

        fs.readdir(dirname,  async function(err, filenames) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error occured reading folder '+ dirname);
                reject('Error occured reading folder ' + dirname);
            }
            for (const filename of filenames) {
                if (filename.split('.').pop() === 'zip') {
                    try {
                        await new Promise((resolve2, reject2) => {
                            gunzip(dirname + filename, `${dirname}${filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf("."))}`, () => {
                                console.log(`${dirname}${filename} unzipped`);
                                fs.unlinkSync(dirname + filename);
                                resolve2();
                            })
                        })
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log('Error', e.message);
                    }
                }
            }
            resolve();
        });
    })
}
```

However, when I push it to the live branch, the server pop this error

[image]

I have no idea why would it work on my local server but not on the live server, if you have any idea I would glady read it. Thanks in advance for people that will try to help.

Comment: You get this error probably because the folder doesn't exist. You should `return reject(...)` instead of just rejecting.

Comment: In the case that the directory is not found, `filenames` will be `undefined` (which is not iterable). See the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/fs.html#fsreaddirpath-options-callback).